# InputStream of Server and Client

Tags: java, inputstream

My question is if the same `InputStream` is provided to both Client and Server.

In my Server side I have:

```
final socket finalAccept=myServerSocket.accept();
finalAccept.getInputStream();
```

for the client(which is multithreaded)i have:

```
HttpURLConnection.getInputStream();
```

now can it happen that both of them simultaneously read the InputStream resulting in data corruption

actually my server is NANOHttpd server and client is my implementation.Upto 10-12 runs request,response is okay,but after that the client read data is empty and so is the server's inputstream.available()=0.can it be the above specified problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `InputStream` of the client receives the data from the `OutputStream` of the server, and vice versa. That's the whole point - each side receives the data sent from the other.

Comment: Can u please clarify that if the server is reading data from InputStream and as the client is multiThreaded the (another thread)client does the getInputStream and reads the InputStream exactly the same time as server is reading InputStream..will there be data corruption..?

Comment: @ManasL: No, because the client would be reading from the server's output, and the server would be reading from the client's output. Think of the socket as having two independent unidirectional streams of data: one from the client to the server, and one from the server to the client. (At a low level I doubt that they're *that* independent, but you can think of them as being independent at a high level.)

Comment: They're only interdependent in the sense that the same socket gives access to both sides and that closing or resetting affects them both. Apart from that, the two sides are really quite unrelated, at least until you get down to media access and carriers and collisions.

Comment: @EJP: I was wondering whether a packet could contain an ACK for having read some data, and also some outbound data as well. I haven't looked at the low level stuff for a while :)

Comment: actually my server is NANOHttpd server and client is my implementation.Upto 10-12 runs request,response is okay,but after that the client read data is empty and so is the server's inputstream.available()=0.so i thought that it may be the above specified problem.

Comment: @ManasL: `available()` shows how much data is available *right now*. It doesn't mean that there isn't any more data on the way. You haven't really given us enough information to go on, but I suggest you look for a problem elsewhere.

Comment: Can it be that if i wait for some time the data may be available in InputStream..?@EJP

Comment: @ManasL: Well that's normally why you call `read(...)` which will block until data is available. However, this is now moving away from the question as you asked it - and Stack Overflow isn't an interactive debugging environment. I suggest you go away and work on the problem with the new information, then ask a new question with more details if you're still stuck.